# Differential Amplifier Output - Analog Devices Calculator

Tags: differential-amplifier

[image: Calculator Result]

Dear All,
Below it shown the output of an automated calculator provided by Analog Devices for calculating the inputs and outputs of a differential amplifier [Calc_Link](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/interactive-design-tools/adi-diffampcalc.html).
For the output shown VoutP = {2...3...2...1...2}, VoutN = {2...1...2...3...2} the expected differential output at an input of an ADC would be Vdiff = {0...1...0...-2...0}. As you can see from the grey line at the output this is not the case. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Once an answer is given that points out your error, you should not adjust your question like you did. I have rolled back your question to the original.

Comment: Could you please delete your answer so that I can change my question, as it does not offer nothing else other than highlighting a typo error?

Comment: Ask a brand new question is my advice to you and be careful about what you post. With reference to the grey line, you need to be clear about where it is and what it is. All the grey lines I see in the picture appear to be correct. if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> *For the output shown VoutP = {2...3...2...1...2}, VoutN =
> {2...1...2...3...2} the expected differential output at an input of an
> ADC would be Vdiff = {0...1...0...-2...0}. As you can see from the
> grey line at the output this is not the case.*

- If VoutP is 2...3...2...1...2 and,
- If VoutN is 2...1...2...3...2 then, the expected differential would be this: -

0, 2, 0, -2, 0 and **NOT** what you assert.

You assert this: 0, \$\color{blue}{\textbf{1}}\$, 0, -2, 0 and clearly the 2nd digit from the left (in blue) is wrong.

> *What is the reasoning behind this?*

Only you can address this.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the typo error. Can you still explain why the output with the grey line is 2...4...2...0...2 and not 0, 2, 0, -2, 0.

Comment: The output grey line is biased by 2 volts with the Vocm pin set to 2 volts.